# How to connect to Azure Table/Cosmos storage emulator

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-emulator

The docs here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-emulator) say the endpoint should be this format to access emulated table storage:

```
http://127.0.0.1:10002/<account-name>/<resource-path>
```

However, where do I get the `<account-name>` and `<resource-path>` items from within the emulator?

Anyone know of a working demo for connecting to the emulator?  The only one I seem to find is for connecting to Azure.

Answer (score 6):

If we want to connect to the storage emulator, the code demo is the same as Azure Storage. The difference is the storage emulator uses a well-known account name and key.

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;
AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;
```

> To target the storage emulator, you can use a shortcut that maps to the well-known account name and key.

In that case, your connection string setting is:

```
<add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;" />
```

We could get the code demo from Azure's official documentation.

```
// Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the table client.
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

// Retrieve a reference to the table.
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");

// Create the table if it doesn't exist.
table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Regarding how to use Cosmos emulator, we may get the answer from [Use the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator for local development and testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator).

We need to install the [Cosmos emulator](https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-emulator) locally.

> his account and key are the only credentials permitted for use with the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator. They are:

```
Account name: localhost:<port>
Account key: C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
```

Demo code:

```
// Connect to the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator running locally
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(
    new Uri("https://localhost:8081"), 
    "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==");
```

Comment: I've installed the emulator and I have run the sample code but it fails on the line *table.CreateIfNotExists();* with exception "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 'Unable to connect to the remote server' - SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Comment: It seems that you don't start the **Azure Storage Emulator**. We also could find how to start it from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-emulator#start-and-initialize-the-storage-emulator) you mentioned

Comment: It is started.  I can see the local web site it runs.

Comment: I assume that you start the [Cosmos Db emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator) not  [Azure storage emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-emulator).

Comment: Yes I am running Cosmos Emulator.  I just realised I was using *Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage* and not *Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage-PremiumTable -Version 0.1.0-preview -Pre* so it connects to Azure but still fails as soon as I change the connection string to "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;"

Comment: From the  [Cosmos Db emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator) document, we could know that it is not currently supported the creation of tables and graphs. `At this time the Data Explorer in the emulator only supports the creation of DocumentDB API collections and MongoDB collections. The Data Explorer in the emulator does not currently support the creation of tables and graphs.`

Comment: About Premium and standard Table APIs, please refer to [Introduction to Azure Cosmos DB: Table API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-introduction)